# MySQL/Doctrine: Find Children for items with same name

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three Doctrine entity classes, let's call them Top, Middle, and Bottom.

Top has a one-to-many relationship to middle and middle has a one-to-many relationship to bottom.

Middle has a property "name". This "name" does not need to be unique.

Now I am trying to display a list of "middles". All middles with the same name should be grouped (appearing only once in the list).

Under each list item there shall be a preview of related bottoms (max 5 for example)

### Example

Database contents:

```
Top Lorem:
   - Middle Foo
        - Bottom Dolor
        - Bottom Sit
        - Bottom Amet
   - Middle Bar
        - Bottom Elit

Top Ipsum:
   - Middle Foo
        - Bottom Aenean 
        - Bottom Comodo
   - Middle Baz
        - Bottom Aenean
```

Expected result:

```
- Middle Foo
    - Bottom Dolor
    - Bottom Sit
    - Bottom Amet
    - Bottom Aenean
- Middle Bar
    - Bottom Elit 
- Middle Baz
    - Bottom Aenean
```

Here are the three classes described with doctrine annotations:

#### Top

```
/**
 * Handelsunternehmen
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="top")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bundle\Repository\TopRepository")
 */
class Top extends Client
{

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bundle\Entity\Middle", mappedBy="top", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $middles;

    ...
}
```

#### Middle

```
/**
 * Middle
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="middle")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bundle\Repository\MiddleRepository")
 */
class Vertriebsschiene
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;


    /**
     * @var Top
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\Entity\Top")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="top_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $top;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bottom", mappedBy="middle")
     */
    private $bottoms;

    ...
}
```

Bottom

```
/**
 * Bottom
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="bottom")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Bundle\Repository\BottomRepository")
 */
class Bottom extends Lieferant
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"adressCity", "adressStreet"})
     * @ORM\Column(length=128, unique=true)
     */
    protected $slug;

     /**
      * @var Middle
      *
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\Entity\Middle", inversedBy="bottoms")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="middle_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      */
     private $middle;

     ...
 }
```

Currently I retrieve the list of middle objects through the following method:

```
public function findAllQuery(){

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
        ->select('m as middle', 'b as bottom')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(b) as bottom_count')
        ->leftJoin('m.bottoms', 'b')
        ->groupBy('m.name');

    return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

The problem I face is, that `bottom_count` shows the right number of related bottoms, but when I access `middle.bottoms` I only get one result.

Can anybody offer any help? I have been stumped for a week.

Comment: please add examples what you have tried to retrieve the list of `Middle` objects.

Comment: I just added the function `findAllQuery()`. Thats how I retrieve the middle objects